# How to know the value of the INT sequential I just INSERTed in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have these tables (simplified for clarity):

```
TABLE CHANGES
ChangeID  bigint
MemberID  varchar(10)
ChangedOn smalldatetime

TABLE FIELDCHANGES
ChangeID  bigint
FieldName varchar(30)
OldValue  varchar(100)
NewValue  varchar(100)
```

In order to keep track of changes made to a Member (`MemberID`).

What I want to do is `INSERT` a record in `CHANGES`, with SQL generating sequential value (by using `IsIdentity`) for the `ChangeID` column and then `INSERT` a record in `FIELDCHANGES` with that value and the other details.
Now, I could `INSERT` and then `SELECT` the latest record for that `MemberID`, but I was wondering if there was an efficient way to do this, like SQL returning the value of the `ChangeID` column when doing that `INSERT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the identity value of the most recently inserted identity column, use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

The scope is specific to a stored proc, script batch, function or trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `OUTPUT` clause in your inserts. This is the preferred method because it allows you to insert multiple records and still get all the identities out. `Scope_identity` will only return one record. Further, `scope_identity` has some problems when parallelism is turned on. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) If you are not using parallelism and you will only ever be inserting one record, `scope_identity` will work.

There are two other ways to get an identity value returned, but in this use case there are no circumstances in which you should use them. `@@identity` will return the last identity from the scope you are in, which means that if the table has a trigger that inserts to a table with an identity, that is the identity you get returned. `@@identity` for this use case is likely to eventually (and very sneakily, because it will happily use the wrong identity sometimes for a long time before the problem is discovered and then it is almost impossible to fix) give you data integrity problems and should never be used for this case because you never know when a trigger might be added. `@@identity` is dangerous precisely because it may break in maintenance with no clue that it has broken until someone complains about the data integrity being bad.

Even worse is `ident_current`. This will take the last identity from any scope, so if two users insert at the same time, it may return the wrong identity value to at least one of them. This causes major data integrity problems. The purpose of `ident_current` is to see what the last identity on the table was; it should never be used to insert to another table.

Comment: I can't figure how to use this `OUTPUT`. Could you give me a hint?